# Result no initialized?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods, return

```
import java.util.*;

//Creates a program which allows the user to find the factorial of a number

public class forLoop {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number you want the factorial from: ");
        int number = input.nextInt(); // user input
        input.close();

        int result_2 = getFactorial(number); //initializes getFactorial method
        System.out.println("The factorial of " + number + " is " + result); //prints results

        }

    public static int getFactorial (int num1) {
        int result;

        for (int times = num1; times <= 1; times--) { //repeats loop until times <=1

            result = num1 * (num1 - 1); //does the factorial equation

        }

        return result;  // returns results (here is the problem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler cannot assume that the loop would execute at least once - a necessary condition for the `result` to get assigned.

Change declaration of `result` as follows to fix the problem:

```
int result = 1;
```

This would help your code compile, but it would not fix the logical error in calculating the factorial: currently, your loop would run indefinitely because of a wrong loop condition.

You should be multiplying numbers from `1` to `num1`, inclusive. Change the loop condition so `times >= 1` instead of `times <= 1`, and the loop body to `result *= times` to fix this error.

Comment: IMO, `int result = 1;` might be better because the program is about factorial. And there is another error in the main method. The SOP which prints the final result.

Comment: @R.J There's a logical error there, I'll write some more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to intialize this variable:

```
int result;
```

Like this:

```
int result = 0; //Which ever intial value you want
```

Because compiler will not be sure that for loop will be always executed.

Answer (score 0):

since you are assigning the function return value to `result_2`, you should print that instead of result

try

```
System.out.println("The factorial of " + number + " is " + result_2);
```

And you are need to initialize local variable before using them

Answer (score 0):

The condition of for loop is incorrect

it shoud be

```
for (int times = num1; times >= 1; times--)
{

            result *= times; //this wil calculate right factorial

}
```

also initialize result to 1 before for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
int result;

    for (int times = num1; times <= 1; times--) { //repeats loop until times <=1

        result = num1 * (num1 - 1); //does the factorial equation

    }
```

This block is causing the error. If the loop does not run even once due to this

> times <=1

condition java wont have anything to print here

```
System.out.println("The factorial of " + number + " is " + result);
```

So here comes the need of initialization which acts as a default value to print.
So the solution will be to replace

```
int result;
```

with

```
int result=1; // note that I am not initializing with 0 as that will cause every factorial to become zero.
```

there is another mistake in your code instead of

```
times <= 1
```

it should be

```
times >= 1
```

Your code will probably not run even once for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize `int result` to something:

```
int result = 0;
```

Because your loop isn't executing (`times` is already greater than 1), it is trying to return an uninitialized variable.